# How can I set a custom image on my website for outlook link preview?

Tags: web, outlook-2010

Ive been getting complaints that when people insert a link in an outlook email that it pulls a url preview paragraph and image.. The image seems to be grabbed at random from within the content of the page..

Is there a way on a website to specify what image / content is grabbed by outlook link preview? I currently use open graph and that does not effect outlook.